# Selenium webdriver. Help draw up a loop with if else

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

When I do:

```
if (driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[contains(@resource-id, 'rl_ali_sign_in_btn')]").size()>0)
else {}
```

I receive:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement "does not contain a definition for the" size "
```

I need to check the existence of the element and if it exists then do an action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `findElementByXPath()` doesn't return a `List` but a `WebElement`. What you need to use is `findElementsByXPath()` (elements, not element).